# I keep getting the error of not finding a symbol what am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays

We have to use an array of 10 double integers in order to get a average of those ten user entered numbers.

AverageArray.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
         double average = average(array[].class);

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AverageArray
{
   public static int average(int[] array)
      {
         int sum = 0;
     int avg = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i< array.length; i++)
        {
           sum += array[i];
        }
     avg = sum / array.length;   
     return avg;
  }


   public static double average(double[] array)
  {
     double sum = 0;
     double avg = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i< array.length; i++)
        {
           sum += array[i];
        }
     avg = sum / array.length;   
     return avg;
  }



   public static void main(String[] Args)
  { 
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     double average = average(array[].class);

     System.out.println("Enter 10 double values: ");
     double[] array = new double[10];
     for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
           array[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }   
     System.out.println(average);



  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a wrong parameter to the `average` method (you should pass `array` and not `array[].class`. You're also calling the method before the user inputs the values to be stored in the array. You should call it after the array is filled.

```
System.out.println("Enter 10 double values: ");
double[] array = new double[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    array[i] = input.nextDouble();
}
double average = average(array);
System.out.println(average);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your error :

```
double average = average(array[].class);
```

`array[].class` is not valid syntax in Java. You can only use `.class` on classes, and you don't have any `array` class.

You are supposed to call your `average` method after initializing the array, and you should pass the array to it :

```
double[] array = new double[10];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    array[i] = input.nextDouble();
} 
double average = average(array);
```